# ASP crash - AD query and problem with AD profiles missing "initials"

Tags: vbscript

I'm running into trouble with my AD query when an AD profile lacks a middle initial. Here's the vbscript snippet

```
strRSUser = "SELECT displayname,givenName,initials,sn,employeeID,postalcode,memberOf,objectCategory,physicaldeliveryoffi cename,mail,manager FROM 'LDAP://" & strDomain &"' WHERE samaccountname = '"& varUser &"' ORDER by name "
rsUser.Open strRSUser, connAD,1,1
```

Make sure recordset is not empty (i.e. this is a valid user) and then set the session variables

```
If NOT (rsUser.BOF AND rsUser.EOF) Then
Dim varInitials
Session("userAccess") = 1
varEmail = rsUser.Fields.Item("mail").Value
varEmployeeID = rsUser.Fields.Item("employeeID").Value
varFirstName = rsUser.Fields.Item("givenName").Value
varInitials = rsUser.Fields.Item("initials").Value
varLastName = rsUser.Fields.Item("sn").Value
varOffice = rsUser.Fields.Item("physicaldeliveryofficename").Value
varInitialsChk = IsEmpty(varInitials)
Session.Timeout = 60

Else
Session("userAccess") = 0

' End valid user check
End If
```

My problem:

I need to account for the possibility that varInitials may be nonexistent. Haven't found a way to do it. Consequently, the javascript line below breaks for users without a middle initial in AD. So far, my only solution is to leave out varInitials entirely, but that's not ideal. When varInitials are present, I want to populate the from field with them:

```
"if(emptyString.test(theForm.ctl00$ctl00$mpcSingleContent$cntrlID_23172.value)) {" & vbCrLf & _
" theForm.ctl00$ctl00$mpcSingleContent$cntrlID_23172.value = """ + varLastName + ", " + varFirstName + " " + varInitials + """" & vbCrLf & _
"}" & vbCrLf & _
```

Who can help?

Comment: Build the values up beforehand then add them to the javascript string. The easiest check is using `If Len(varInitials & "")  > 0 Then`.

Comment: There's a simple trick to avoid empty/NULL variables: `varInitials = "" & rsUser.Fields.Item("initials").Value`. This way, the string is ensured to be initialized, but simply has a length of 0.